# With Mongoose, query document with sub-document input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query my mongodb database using mongoose :

```
DimensionModel.find({details:details}, function(err, obj) {
    console.log("object : "+obj);
});
```

Keeping in mind that my Model looks like this :

```
var DimensionSchema = new Schema({
  label:String,
  details:Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

So basically, all I want, is to query documents using details which is a sub-document.
I got empty result right now, and don't understand why

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Well clearly your object in `details` does not actually match anything in the "details" field of your document. You probably don't want this anyway. See ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in the MongoDB documentation. If you cannot work that out, then without showing what a document looks like or the data you are using to query, then no-one else can really solve it either.

Comment: Your details are not sub-document but rather a mixed type object

Comment: @DoronSinai That how you typically define a "sub-object" without a strict set of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what it is you are passing as query but this example is working:

```
var DimensionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    label:String,
    details:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});

mongoose.model('Dimension', DimensionSchema);

var DimensionModel = mongoose.model('Dimension');

//First let's add a model with the details, than we could find it
var newDimensionModel = new DimensionModel()
newDimensionModel.details = {someDetails:"some details"}
newDimensionModel.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        return;
    }

    //Then we can query it
    DimensionModel.find({details:{someDetails:"some details"}}, function(err, obj) {
        console.log("object : 1" +obj);
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
If your details object is more complex you can also do this:
read here for more: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

```
var details = {
    "detail":"Some detail",
    "detail1":2,
    "detail2":2.5,
    "detail3":{"innerDetail":"detail"}
}

DimensionModel.find({"details.detail":"Some detail", "details.detail1":2, "details.detail2":2.5, "details.detail3":{"innerDetail":"detail"}}, function(err, obj) {
        console.log(obj.length);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but I feel like it's more complicated : in my case details = {} with a lot of stuff inside (depending on object). I want the query to return the document only if all fields in details match. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @ilellouch can you give an example for such details object?

Comment: @ilellouch see my added code, maybe it will be more helpful

Comment: Hey, It's exactly like you said but sometime I'll have details.details1 and sometime details.details2. So basically I'm looking for details.*:details.* (match every elements, if possible)